# How to create SharePoint list item with Microsoft Graph API?

Tags: sharepoint-online, microsoft-graph

I am trying to create list items with Microsoft Graph API to a SharePoint endpoint. My URL is as follows:

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites/{id}.sharepoint.com:/sites/{name of the site}:/lists/{list_id}/items
```

Calling this URL with POST, and a body like this:

```
{
    "fields": {
        "FileLeafRef": "757391.pdf",
        "ContentType": "Document",
        "Application_x0020_Name": "ABC",
    }
}
```

It is giving error as `"message": "Files and folders should only be added to a DocumentLibrary via the OneDrive API"`

Can some one help on this, how to fix this issue?
Here I am trying to create metadata for document, with in a list from Dell Boomi.

Answer (score 1):

The error message is already clear. You can use graph API for SharePoint site when you create a List item only. For files and folder, you need to switch to Graph API for OneDrive